# Perl compare numbers with trailing zeroes (after decimal)

Tags: perl

I'm comparing two numbers in perl:

```
if ($apples + 0 != $fruits->{apples} + 0) {
    print $apples;
    print $fruits->{apples};
    print "\nApples is different.";
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
41.1000
41.1
Apples is different.
```

But for my use case, those should be equal. I've added +0 to the number to try and ensure they are not strings, so they should be equal, what gives?

Comment: Call `printf "%.20f %.20f",$apples,$fruit->{apples}` for enlightenment.

Comment: The problem is in however the variables are being populated, *not* in some floating point limitation.  If they are generated mathematically, it does potentially trigger a floating point problem and doing +0 doesn't change anything .  If they are coming from strings, `==` will still work because both values will convert to the same float representation.

Comment: This question should not have been closed as a duplicate because the problem is not in the comparison.  It's something upstream.  
`$foo = "41.1"; $bar = "41.1000"; print $foo == $bar ? "true":"false";  --> true
`